# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Toggle Menu Transition

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen the documentation of Bootstrap 4 about the navbar. In previous version of Bootstrap (3.x), when we click the navbar toggle, the menu will show by sliding down (a kind of transition). But, in Bootstrap 4, it seems the transition effect has eliminated. How can I add the effect again?

Thanks.

Comment: The Bootstrap 4 Navbar [transition works perfectly fine in all the support browsers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/browsers-devices/#supported-browsers).

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 we also have the same transition animation on navbar toggle. You can check the navbar code snippet here https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/navbar-logo/

Comment: Well, I tried on Chrome and it works well. But it doesn't work on Firefox. What's was going on? Any solution?

Comment: Include these lines of code in between head tag `<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`